# SQL Query does not fetch the required data in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, sql, sqlite, join

I am getting data from sqlite table using join in iphone application it fetches the data fine but it does not get the data accurate here is my query

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster LEFT JOIN  Category  ON  ContentMaster.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID  LEFT JOIN Topic ON ContentMaster.TopicID=Topic.TopicID where ContentMaster.ContentTagText='%@' OR ContentMaster.ContentTitle='%@' AND Category.CategoryName='%@' AND Topic.TopicName='%@'",appDelegate.tagInput,appDelegate.tagInput,appDelegate.categoryName,appDelegate.topicName];
NSLog(@"Select is %@",select);
```

Let Say If `CategoryName='Product'` and `Topic='M2M Operations'`, `ContentTagText='Office'` and also `ContentTitle='Office'` so when result comes it shows all the records of the `ContentTag='Office'` but it does not show only those records where `ContentTag='Office'` and `CategoryName='product'` and `Topic='M2M Operations'`. I think may be i am missing operators, any idea how to tackle this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand your question, you are missing parenthesis around `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM ContentMaster
LEFT JOIN  Category ON ContentMaster.CategoryID=Category.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN Topic ON ContentMaster.TopicID=Topic.TopicID
WHERE (ContentMaster.ContentTagText='%@' OR ContentMaster.ContentTitle='%@')
  AND Category.CategoryName='%@'
  AND Topic.TopicName='%@'
```

Answer (score 0):

open a Terminal session in the folder that contains your sqlite database and run the command sqlite3; at the prompt enter your sql and see what results you get and amend until you get the results you're looking for.

To get at the sqlite database file in Terminal:

Run the app in the simulator;

NSLog the path of the folder that has the sqlite database;

copy/paste this path to a Finder window using menu Go to Folder..;

drag the folder from Finder on top of your Terminal icon in the dock, or open the Terminal app from Applications and cd to this path;

Comment: sqlite data base has the data stored in app how will i check that in terminal windo

Comment: answer edited to include how to get at the folder containing the database

Comment: use firefox sqlitemanager addon you will get data ~library-application support- simulator-your application - your.db